# "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767

Tags: python, django

i am new to django i have created new project project. when i start a server and load for the  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in console it says that.

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.3\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/sanjel/Desktop/onlyfortest/manage.py runserver 8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 16, 2018 - 20:26:40
Django version 1.9.13, using settings 'onlyfortest.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[16/Apr/2018 20:26:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
```

i you have solution please let me know

Comment: so what's wrong with this output?

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 is out of date and no longer supported. If you starting out with Django, then use 2.0.x (or 1.11.x if you can't use Python 3).

Comment: @Ivan Vinogradov ,                                                                            Not Found: /
[16/Apr/2018 20:26:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767                                My question is why is it showing above

Comment: @Alasdair ,thank you for your good advice

Answer (score 2):

Likely because there's nothing to load. If you've just created your project, you'll need to edit your views.py, urls.py, and a html template to really see anything. Don't worry too much about a not found error right now if you haven't created anything.

If you're brand new take a crack at the [Django Development Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/)